# Connection not open in using statement

Tags: c#, mysql, connection

While using MySql I get the following error in my aspnetcore app.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> at bdtFood.Controllers.PersonController.GetAll(Int32 id)
>
> at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.
> d__28.MoveNext()

Here is the code which I use:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM person";
    Modells.Person helpPerson;
    using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            helpPerson = new Modells.Person(reader.GetInt32(0), reader[1].ToString(), reader[2].ToString(), reader[3].ToString(), reader[4].ToString(), reader.GetInt32(5));
            persons.Add(helpPerson);
        }
    }
}
```

The connection should be open the time the reader acts. but it is not. While debugging the connetion is closed.
EDIT: `MySqlDataReader reader;` is declared in the controller class.

Comment: You aren't [calling `SqlConnection.Open()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx) anywhere that I can see.

Comment: What makes you think the connection should be open when you haven't opened it?

Comment: The ```SqlClient``` also doesn't auto-open a connection when you start using it with a Command. Manage the status of your connection by calling ```.Open()``` and ```.Close()``` at appropriate times.

Comment: ok using does not automaticly open and close the connection? thought this is the case.

Comment: ```using``` _disposes_ of the connection when it is no longer used. It _does not_ automatically open connections.

Comment: ok thank u for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the `SqlConnection` before using it. The `using` statement does only dispose the object if it is no longer in use. Thats the reason why any object you want to use in a using block (declared in the paranthesis) needs ti implement `IDisposable`. You problem should be solved by this:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM person";
    Modells.Person helpPerson;
    using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            helpPerson = new Modells.Person(reader.GetInt32(0), reader[1].ToString(), reader[2].ToString(), reader[3].ToString(), reader[4].ToString(), reader.GetInt32(5));
            persons.Add(helpPerson);
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```